# Java: Everything is an object

Tags: java, class, oop

Let's take the very simple code:

```
public class MyProg {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

MyProg is a class. My question is how can we instantiate an object from this class? Where is the constructor method that must be in any class? What causes "MyProg" to behave like just any other ordinary class in Java.

Comment: _"The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors."_ For more infos, read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a replacement for a Java book or tutorial. Your question is answered in any chapter on classes and objects. Your question shows no research effort.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning java

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is covered by any half-decent Java book or tutorial.

Comment: Not everything in Java is an object. For example, primitive types: `int`, `long`, `boolean`...

Comment: @Lashane that's ridiculous. Learning programming languages on SO is now prohibited?

Comment: @djechlin yes, as it always was, to learn language you should use books/online resources and SO is for specific questions/problems

Comment: Believe it or not - I study Java from the book "Java Softwre Solutions". This point is not perfectly clear in the book, so I decided to ask here. Besides, even if I use a book/tutorial, it's reasonable that I don't understand it fully. That's why this forum exists.

Answer (score 2):

You could write `new MyProg()` if you wanted to create an object of this class.  But there's not much point in doing so, because this class stores no data, and has no non-static methods; so an object of it won't be at all useful.

The constructor for it is automatically generated by the compiler.  But you could add your own constructor(s) if you didn't want this to happen.

Good luck with learning Java.  But I don't think asking questions on Stack Overflow is the best way to begin.  You might be better off if you use the online Java tutorials, or invest in a book.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a MyProg:

```
MyProg myProg = new MyProg();
```

This is a perfectly valid class just like any other class. It just doesn't have any methods, so it doesn't do all that much.

What's special about your "main" class is that the JVM is told to just run the `main` method. It's very common to have a class like this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        // do stuff with app
    }
}
```

which is a case where the `main` method will first instantiate an object of that class. Please note that `main` is always `static`, which is what disassociates it from the object, and lets you not have to think about objects when learning to write your first Java program.

Answer (score 1):

You have not created an object of the class. If you did not provide a constructor, the *Java compiler will add a default no argument constructor*.

```
MyProg(){
  //This is the default no argument constructor.
}
```

**Some more points about default constructor(As per JLS):**

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor that takes no parameters is automatically provided.
>   If the class is declared public, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier public.
>   If the class is declared protected, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier protected.
>   If the class is declared private, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier private. 
>   Otherwise the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier.

To Instantiate an object you have to do like:

```
MyProg myProg = new MyProg();
```

The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.